# Redirect local connections to another server?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, redirect, connection

I want to develop a program, not language specific, that can redirect ANY connection to another one, like a proxy server, but for all connections. The language doesn't really matter, but is there a way to do this without modifying raw windows apis and such? I'm going to attempt this in java, but I can import C and C++ code with JNI. Also, what about mac/linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is the wrong language to attempt to do this in.  Even if it is possible (e.g. on Windows), the real work would need to be done either using external utilities, or using native library calls.

Attempting to do this for multiple operating systems makes this even harder.  The implementation mechanisms are bound to be different.

---

I don't know how you would do this in Windows, but on a modern Linux system you might do this using "iptables" to enable and configure the network packet processing in the OS kernel.  This requires root privilege, a good understanding of the way that network protocols, and care ... since it is easy to "brick" your networking to the degree that you need console-level access to recover.

(And if you are using OS-level virtualization, it can get particularly complicated ...)

FWIW - It is possible to install and use a port of "iptables" on Mac OS/X ... thought it is apparently not supported by Apple.

---

On the other hand, if you are simply trying to have a Java application direct all of *its own* outgoing network connections via some kind of proxy, then you should be able to do this by configuring a custom `SocketFactory` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You should certainly consider/evaluate using TCP/UDP splice. It is a well-known mechanism for building proxies and is fairly efficient in terms of copying data form one connection to another.

URL: http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice